# How to display the "correct" card data in dialog with MUI

Tags: reactjs, firebase, material-ui

I am trying to implement an option to open a dialog for the corresponding card, using MUI Card, CardAction and Dialog.

Currently I'm getting all the data from Firebase and display each of them in an individual card, with a button to view it in a dialog. As of right now this button will only open a dialog and display the last fetched data no matter which card I select.

How can I display the correct card data in the dialog, depending on which card I clicked the button on?

E.g: I press "view more" on the 4th card and the dialog will only load the data from the 4th card.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getEvents = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(eventsRef);

      data.forEach((doc) => {
        setEventList(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
      })
    };
    getEvents();
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div className="stepper-title" style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
          <b><h1>Aankomende afspraken</h1></b><br></br><p>Prik een afspraak die jou intereseerd</p>
      </div>
      <div className="event-list-container">
        {
          eventList && eventList.map(event => {
            {count++}
            return (
              <div key={event.id}>
                <Card variant="outlined" sx={{ width: 250 }}>
                  <CardContent>
                      <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 14 }} color="text.secondary" gutterBottom>
                        {event.date}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography variant="h5" component="div">
                        {event.occasion.title}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography sx={{ mb: 1.5 }} color="text.secondary">
                        {event.location}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography variant="body2">
                        {event.occasion.description}
                      </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                  <CardActions>
                    card {count}
                    <Button onClick={handleClickOpen} size="small" eventid={event.id}>bekijken</Button>
                    <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} PaperProps={{elevation: 1}} hideBackdrop>
                      {count}
                      <DialogContent>
                        <TextField
                          label="Titel"
                          defaultValue={event.occasion.title}
                          fullWidth
                          variant="standard"
                        />
                        <TextField
                          label="Description"
                          defaultValue={event.occasion.description}
                          fullWidth
                          variant="standard"
                        />
                        <TextField
                          label="Datum"
                          defaultValue={event.date}
                          fullWidth
                          variant="standard"
                        />
                        <TextField
                          label="Locatie"
                          defaultValue={event.location}
                          fullWidth
                          variant="standard"
                        />
                        <TextField
                          label="Naam"
                          defaultValue={event.organizer.name}
                          fullWidth
                          variant="standard"
                        />
                        <TextField
                          label="E-mailadres"
                          defaultValue={event.organizer.email}
                          fullWidth
                          variant="standard"
                        />
                      </DialogContent>
                      <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose}>terug</Button>
                        <Button onClick={handleClose}>Aanpassen</Button>
                      </DialogActions>
                    </Dialog>
                  </CardActions>
                </Card>
              </div>
              )
          })
        }
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: pass id of doc or save in local variable state then you can just make request to firebase with that id or `eventList.map((event, index)` get index then save it local variable and you can get correct data like `<DialogContent> <TextField defaultValue={eventList[index]....sion.title}  />`

Answer (score 0):

I am also strucked in same problem
-I think we should use "id" of the data

Comment: Hey, the issue was that this code opened ALL the dialogs at once. This made it seem that only 1 wrong dialog was open, but instead the issue was that all the dialog overlapped eachother.